# firebase orderByChild() with specified child key doesnt work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get data which has current user uid and sort by time, but somehow my query brings data which has other uid as well

This is my query

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts").orderByChild("uid_timestamp/"+uid).limitToLast(12)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    items.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        items.add(item.getValue(PostModel.class));
                        Log.d("checking","writerUid "+item.getValue(PostModel.class).writerUid);
                    }
```

This is my database

[image]

So the writerUid is in uid_timestamp with the time. Am I using wrong child key? I need your help!

Comment: seems like there will be no child for the specific name "uid_timestamp"+uid

Comment: what does it mean ?? and i forgot to put "/" behind uid_timestamp in that code my code is like orderByChild("uid_timestamp/"+uid)

Comment: i don't think it will work , order by child filters in only one child ,, if you want to filter that you need to add the orginal uid value instead of uid in uid_timestamp,,  like gsf76vhdvc76vvhdchcdgv_timestamp

Comment: @hwan firebase support orderby only upto one level , you can filter your post by unique id but not by uid timestamp

Comment: @JinsonPaul oh i see thank you !

Comment: @Shanmugam oh thank you so much i got it what you mean

Comment: @hwan welcome ...